# Add a comment without refreshing the page

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a comment form and I can add comments, but I have to refresh the page for them to display

the **comment form** looks like this

```
class CommentForm extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      state: this.props.state
    };
   this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.onSubmit(this.state);


  };

  handleChange = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  };

  render() {


    return (
      <div>
        <Paper className="styles" elevation={4}>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <div>
              <TextField
                label="Comment"
                name="comment"
                value={this.state.comment || ""}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
            </div>
            <br />
            <Button type="submit">Save</Button>
          </form>

        </Paper>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    state: state
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getTicket }
)(CommentForm);
```

And this component is for displaying the comments that are saved in the database
**displayComments**

```
class DisplayComments extends PureComponent {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.getAllComments();
  }
  getComment(commentId) {
    this.props.getComment(commentId);
  }

  render() {
    const { comments } = this.props;
    const commentsOnTicket = this.props.data.match.params.id
    const filterComments = comments.filter(comment => comment.tickets.id == commentsOnTicket);

    const commentsList = filterComments.sort((a, b) => {
      return a.id - b.id;
    });
    return (
      <div>
        <Paper className="styles" elevation={4}>
          <h1>comments</h1>
          <table>
            <thead />
            <tbody>
              {commentsList.map(comment => (
                <tr key={comment.id}>
                  <td style={{ border: "2px solid black" }}>
                    {comment.comment}
                  </td>
                  <td />
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <br />
          <br />
        </Paper>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  return {
    comments: state.comments,
    comment: state.comment,
    users: state.users === null ? null : state.users,
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {
    getAllComments,
    getComment,
  }
)(DisplayComments);
```

My knowledge on React is limited since I just started learning about it 
So I'm guessing it should be done with lifecyclehooks 
but I dont really understand them yet.

this is the **Parent component** rendering the commment form and the displaying of the comments

```
class TicketDetails extends PureComponent {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.getAllComments();
  }
  addComment = comment => {
    this.props.addComment(comment);
  };
  render() {
    const { ticket, tickets, comments } = this.props;
    const { users } = ticket;


    return <div>
        <Card className="outer-card">
          <h1>Ticket: {ticket.id}</h1>
          <h2>Price: €{ticket.price}</h2>
          <p>Description: {ticket.description}</p>
          <h2>Image: {ticket.image}</h2>
          <p>Risk: {getRiskfactor(tickets, ticket, users, comments)} %</p>
          <hr />
        </Card>
      <DisplayComments data={this.props}  />
        <CommentForm onSubmit={this.addComment} />
      </div>;
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    ticket: state.ticket,
    users: state.users,
    tickets: state.tickets,
    comments: state.comments
  };
};
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {
    addComment,
    getAllComments
  }
)(TicketDetails);
```

the **TicketDetails** is rendered in the **App** component

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
      <div>
       <TopBar />
       <br/><br/>
          <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
          <Route exact path="/logout" component={LogoutPage} />
          <Route exact path="/signup" component={SignupPage} />

          <Route exact path="/events" component={EventsList} />
          <Route exact path="/addEvent" component={AddEvent} />

           <Route exact path="/events/:id" component={TicketsList} />
          <Route exact path="/tickets/:id" component={TicketDetails} />
          <Route exact path="/addTicket" component={AddTicket} />

          <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/events" />} />

      </div>

      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

**Action/comments.js**

```
import * as request from "superagent";
import {baseUrl} from "../constants";
import {logout} from "./users";
import {isExpired} from "../jwt";

export const GET_ALL_COMMENTS = "GET_ALL_COMMENTS";
export const GET_COMMENT = "GET_COMMENT";
export const ADD_COMMENT = "ADD_COMMENT";

export const getAllComments = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
    const state = getState();
    if (!state.currentUser) return null;
    const jwt = state.currentUser.jwt;
    if (isExpired(jwt)) return dispatch(logout());
    request
        .get(`${baseUrl}/comments`)
        .set("Authorization", `Bearer ${jwt}`)
        .then(response =>
            dispatch({
                type: GET_ALL_COMMENTS,
                payload: response.body.comments
            })
        )

        .catch(err => alert(err));
};

export const getComment = commentId => (dispatch, getState) => {
    const state = getState();
    if (!state.currentUser) return null;
    const jwt = state.currentUser.jwt;

    if (isExpired(jwt)) return dispatch(logout());

    request
        .get(`${baseUrl}/comments/${commentId}`)
        .set("Authorization", `Bearer ${jwt}`)
        .then(response =>
            dispatch({
                type: GET_COMMENT,
                payload: response.body
            })
        )
        .catch(err => alert(err));
};

export const addComment = comment => (dispatch, getState) => {
    const state = getState();
    const jwt = state.currentUser.jwt;

    if (isExpired(jwt)) return dispatch(logout());

    request
        .post(`${baseUrl}/comments`)
        .set("Authorization", `Bearer ${jwt}`)
        .send({
            comment: comment.comment,
            tickets: state.ticket
        })
        .then(response =>
            dispatch({
                type: ADD_COMMENT,
                payload: response.body
            })
        );
};
```

**reducers/comments.js**

```
import { GET_ALL_COMMENTS } from "../actions/comments";

export default function(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case  GET_ALL_COMMENTS:
      return action.payload;

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**reducers/comment.js**

```
import { GET_COMMENT,ADD_COMMENT } from "../actions/comments";

const comment = {};

export default function(state = comment, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_COMMENT:
      return action.payload;

    case ADD_COMMENT:
      return action.payload;

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: in which component TicketDetails is rendered?

Comment: It is rendered in the App Component.
I've added it to the question.

Comment: where is this function which called in ticket details? this.props.addComment(comment);

Comment: Is  this.props.addComment(comment)  a action,I think the redux state is not updating properly

Comment: please show your actions and reducers too

Comment: I've added the actions & reducers

Comment: i have pointed in my answer. please see.

Comment: I think you need to call the get comments actions after an add has been made,else return new comments list in the success call of the add api

Comment: you mean in the action/comments?

Comment: in the component after add is successful you need to call the get all actions.What are you returning after an add has been made?

Comment: .then(response =>
            dispatch({
                type: ADD_COMMENT,
                payload: response.body
            })
        );

Comment: dispatch(AddComment()).then(dispatch(getComment()))

Comment: But the action ADD_COMMENT is already being dispatched?

Answer (score 3):

Although your question seems to be incomplete, but still there are few mistakes in implementation.

1. You have not used your dispatch to props properly. It is meant to connect dispatch to your function so that you donot have to call `this.props.dispatch(func())` explicitly in your function

   ```
   const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
       return {
            addComment: (comment) => dispatch(addComment(comment))
       }
   }
   ```
2. It doesnot seems a good practice to pass your props down to two to three level. Since your class is statful class you can easily get it in your component and even call it with quite a ease.
3. Why would one have a action to get data from store. Actions and reducers are meant to be making changes in store like add, deleting and updating, not for fetching data. For fetching data you are connecting state to props.

UPDATE****

```
// Add import of the action here like import {addComment} from '../.whatever';
class TicketDetails extends PureComponent {
      componentWillMount() {
        this.props.getAllComments();
      }
      addComment = comment => {
        this.props.addComment(comment);
      };
      render() {
        const { ticket, tickets, comments } = this.props;
        const { users } = ticket;


        return <div>
            <Card className="outer-card">
              <h1>Ticket: {ticket.id}</h1>
              <h2>Price: €{ticket.price}</h2>
              <p>Description: {ticket.description}</p>
              <h2>Image: {ticket.image}</h2>
              <p>Risk: {getRiskfactor(tickets, ticket, users, comments)} %</p>
              <hr />
            </Card>
          <DisplayComments data={this.props}  />
            <CommentForm onSubmit={this.addComment} />
          </div>;
      }
    }
    const mapStateToProps = state => {
      return {
        ticket: state.ticket,
        users: state.users,
        tickets: state.tickets,
        comments: state.comments
      };
    };
    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
      return {
        addComment: (comment) => dispatch(addComment(comment)),
        getAllComments: () => dispatch(getAllComments())
      };
    };
    export default connect(
      mapStateToProps,
      mapDispatchToProps 
    )(TicketDetails);
```

Comment: in every component you have done this kind of thing.

Comment: yes this seems like a good idea 
although it complains that getAllComments(); in the componentWillMount 
is not a function 
since its not being exported in the connect (how to add that?)

Comment: the import of addComment is already there btw.
I've done the same as in your example
but the error I'm getting is about the 
      componentWillMount() {
        this.props.getAllComments();
      }

since it's not being exported anymore.

Comment: Ah I added it to the mapDispatchToProps

Comment: yes and I implemented the update,
but still to see the new comment
I have to refresh the page.

Comment: const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    addComment: (comment) => dispatch(addComment(comment)),
    getAllComments
  };
};
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,

)(TicketDetails);

Comment: check my mapDispatchToProps

Comment: yes, I've tried that as well, but still, have to refresh to see the new comment.
maybe its something in the handle submit or I should use another lifecyclehook ??